# htaccess rewrite rule for specific ajax url

Tags: ajax, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/admin-ajax.php(.*)$ dl-file.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]
```

to protect worpdress files which are called with admin-ajax.php from not logged in users. But this breaks ajax for all visitors - so some things won't work for non registered users.

How could I instead just specify a rewriterule for a specific url, for instance this one:

```
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=ajax_request&fn=download&id=(.*) [QSA,L]
```

id would be a number for a file. 
is there a way to do this with htaccess?

I followed user hakre https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37144/how-to-protect-uploads-if-user-is-not-logged-in using dl-file.php

Thank you!

AD

Comment: What is the destination url you are trying to rewrite to?

Comment: Hello Starkee, it's the upload folder in wp-content. Thanks

Comment: Your `RewriteRule` is missing the target URL. Now sure how it is working.

Comment: I edited the question, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another `RewriteCond` based on `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable to target a specific URL:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)action=ajax_request&fn=download&id= [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/admin-ajax\.php$ dl-file.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Hi Anubhava! Thank you very much! This seems to be exactly the way to go. Thank you!